# Keycloak does not redirect to https

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect

I have a keycloak installed in a host without SSL so my Keycloak server is accessed by HTTP.
This is my keycloak configuration in a docker-compose:

`   keycloak:

```
image: jboss/keycloak:10.0.2
restart: always
depends_on:
  - keycloak-db
networks:
  - keycloak-net
ports:
  - "8180:8080"
environment:
  DB_VENDOR:   POSTGRES
  DB_ADDR:     keycloak-db
  DB_PORT:     5432
  DB_DATABASE: keycloak
  DB_USER:     keycloak
  DB_PASSWORD: password
  KEYCLOAK_USER:     admin
  KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING:  "true"
  JDBC_PARAMS: "useSSL=true"
  REDIRECT-SOCKET: "proxy-https"
```

`

Then when my application does loging with keycloak and try to redirect to https://host/service-name, keycloak replace https by http and my login fails. This is a dev enviroment and that is the reason which I use http instead of https for keycloak.

My configuration in keycloak is:
Clien-protocol: openid-connect
access-type: confidential
standar flow: enabled
directa access grants: enabled
service accounts: enabled
authorization: enabled.

valid redirects uri:
https://host/service-name

Host is my EKS host y service-name is the name of my application. For example, https://eks.host/location

Any idea about how can I redirect to my application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you maybe add more details? like what keycloak-config does your app use to login (e.g oidc config), which url is called while login (what redirect url is set?), what is `https://host/service-name`, the applications url or keycloaks url?, ...

Comment: https://host/service-name , is my host when I redirect from keycloak and service-name is my service name. My service is deployed in EKS, so I have a EKS host and a service name, for example. https://eks.api.bla/locations.  I edit my ask